# Ubuntu 13.04 - Excessive Fan Noise

Tags: 13.04, hp, fan

I know this question has been posted several times - but I am not able to find a convincing solution. The problem is simple - there is excessive fan noise when I am running Ubuntu 13.04, and no this is not a hardware problem, it all runs fine and smooth when I am on Windows 8.

Machine : HP Pavillion DV6, Ubuntu 13.04 x64

It's a fairly common problem, and a simple solution that 'just works' would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clean you fans. many of times due to dust, these issue occurs.

Also, You need to install the Graphic Card Driver. HP should have provided you with either NVIDIA or ATI Raedon

**NVIDIA Graphic Card** -

Just go to "Software Source" app -> Addition Drivers and select Proprietary Driver. It will install the driver for you. Then restart the machine.

**ATI Catalyst - ATI Raedon Driver**

Do not use Additional Drivers for ATI. Its giving problem for me atleast. I followed below steps:

First of all download - ATI Catalyst driver from official site. I am using beta version and its working beautifully. Download the driver from [Official ATI Catalyst Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64)

Execute below steps in terminal sequentially:

*For building ATI packages for Ubuntu 13.04*

Extract the ATI Driver archive to a folder.

```
sudo sh ./amd-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

*32 bit packages - required if you are using 64bit OS*

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
```

*Normally required packages*

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-core libgcc1
```

*Remove old fglrx drivers if any(I advise to execute this to avoid any problems)*

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

*Now, again go to terminal and execute below*

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
sudo reboot
```

**If required you can also install TLP. It will improve battery life.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

I hope, your problem will be solved. Do write back for any further issues.

Comment: Yeah, I have the ATI drivers installed already. I don't understand how this could have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most of times it could be about your graphic card gets warm and because your graphic card is integrated into your cpu the system thinks that cpu gets warm

install `mesa-utils` and `mesa-utils-extras` and reboot  , for installing use the following command-

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

it will work for Intel Graphic Cards

If you are having NVIDIA graphic card then use bumblebee because mesa and NVIDIA will conflict with each other for sure.. to install bumblebee use-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing
```

then for 12.04 and 13.04 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

otherwise  for 13.10 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

If that doesnt work, try to

1. `Cleaning your laptop`- As might be its because of just that, stopping fan from running  properly.
2. `Update bios` - After updating it can perform good operations like increasing compatibility .That solved my issue.
3. `Update Kernel`

hope the very first suggestion will resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using the Radeon Graphics Drivers

Comment: i dont have any specific idea regarding  Radeon Graphics Drivers, but you must try to update your kernel and BIOS, dont updrade to any un-offical BIOS version, check that on official vendors Website.

Comment: @Sushantp606 I have intel n its didn't work for me

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar the best u can do is .. clean your system from inside .. i dont know what the hack its problem . Even now sometimes CPU usage got to 100% and then also it starts running fast . that too without opening any software . Anyways have a try . And i will find a better solution ASAP .